# How do I solve a version confliction problem between albumentations and sentry-sdk?

Tags: python, pandas, sentry, python-poetry

I am using albumentations(ver. 1.1.0) and pandas(ver. 1.4.2) in my poetry project.
And I would like to add [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/) to my project.
However, the albumentations Library depends on Scikit-learn, and sk-learn depends on pillow(Over ver. 9.1.1). In contrast, sentry-sdk depends on pillow 9.0.1, eventually the version solving fails.
Here is the error log.

```
SolverProblemError


  Because sentry (22.8.0) depends on pillow (9.0.1)
   and no versions of sentry match >22.8.0,<23.0.0, sentry (>=22.8.0,<23.0.0) requires pillow (9.0.1).
  So, because tag-predicter depends on both Pillow (^9.1.1) and sentry (^22.8.0), version solving failed.
```

Similar problem occur for Pandas.

```
SolverProblemError

  Because no versions of pandas match >1.4.2,<1.4.3 || >1.4.3,<1.4.4 || >1.4.4,<2.0.0
   and pandas (1.4.2) depends on pytz (>=2020.1), pandas (>=1.4.2,<1.4.3 || >1.4.3,<1.4.4 || >1.4.4,<2.0.0) requires pytz (>=2020.1).
  And because pandas (1.4.4) depends on pytz (>=2020.1)
   and pandas (1.4.3) depends on pytz (>=2020.1), pandas (>=1.4.2,<2.0.0) requires pytz (>=2020.1).
  Because no versions of sentry match >22.8.0,<23.0.0
   and sentry (22.8.0) depends on pytz (2018.9), sentry (>=22.8.0,<23.0.0) requires pytz (2018.9).
  Thus, sentry (>=22.8.0,<23.0.0) is incompatible with pandas (>=1.4.2,<2.0.0).
  So, because tag-predicter depends on both pandas (^1.4.2) and sentry (^22.8.0), version solving failed.
```

What should I do to solve those problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used wrong package name `sentry` instead of correct package name `sentry-sdk`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).